# How can I run node js in apache server 8000 and 2000 port?

Tags: node.js, linux, apache, lamp

I have two websites with node js. I want this site to run 8000 port when I write example-site1.com and to run 2000 port when I write example-site2.com.

When I write only IP:8000 or IP:2000 its works true.

How can I set config?

Answer (score 0):

var ports = process.argv.splice(2)

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) { }); server.listen(ports[0], function () {    console.log('server listening on port '+ports[0]);

node app.js port